# Using class template without arg list (undeclared identifier)

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I am new to class templates and am having trouble. I have a function that doesn't declare  (ie. to be an int, double etc).  But it doesn't make sense to declare  in this function.  Therefore I am getting errors. Thanks for the help.

I have the following function:

```
bool QueType<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const
// Returns true if there are no elements on the queue and false otherwise.
{
    return (front == NULL);
}
```

This returns the following errors:

Error   1   error C2065: 'ItemType' : undeclared identifier 
Error   2   error C2955: 'QueType' : use of class template requires template argument list
Error   3   error C2509: 'IsEmpty' : member function not declared in 'QueType'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
template <typename ItemType>
bool QueType<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const
// Returns true if there are no elements on the queue and false otherwise.
{
    return (front == NULL);
}
```

Comment: Ha Ha.  So much time wasted because I missed one line of code :)  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `template <typename ItemType>` before your function declaration.